# Android - class.getResource() can't find file

Tags: android

I have a file placed in the same package as `MyClass.java` that I need to load at runtime. I am using this code:

```
MyClass.class.getResource("file.xml")
```

however, the result is always `null`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.yourfile);

Comment: It's not a drawable. I am loading it because I need its file path in order to pass it to a library method

Comment: Since its an `XML`, you can store it in the `res/xml/` folder and then fetch it by using `XmlPullParserxpp=getResources().getXml(R.xml.file);`

Comment: do you want to put the url in this file?? and then you want to pass that url in library?? @AlessandroRoaro

Comment: @rup35h yes, that's what I need to do.

Comment: @AndyFaizan that won't work, I need the path

Comment: @AlessandroRoaro check now my answer

Comment: @AlessandroRoaro what do you mean by path??

Comment: @AlessandroRoaro is it woking?

Comment: If you've solved your problem, post the solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by placing the file in R.raw folder, and then copying it at runtime. By doing this I was able to get the file path.